# multer: unexpected field on request post with audio and image file

Tags: node.js, express, multer

My first try was to upload an audio file and it was a success, I use mp3.single('mp3File') as on the docu, and then I try adding another file which is an image file, so I try multer fields, I don't know if I'm doing the right thing so please guide me with this,

And one more thing, I'm trying to save the file as file.originalname, but it doesn't work like that

here's my serve.js

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const app = express();
const port = 3334 || 5000;

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("public"));

const url = process.env.MONGO_URL;
mongoose.connect(url, { useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true });
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", error => console.log(error));
db.once("open", () => console.log("Connected to database"));

const songRouter = require("./routes/song");
app.use("/song", songRouter);

// 400 Error setup
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error("Not Found");
  error.status(400);
  next(error);
});
// ============================================= //
// 500 Error setup
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port: ${port}`);
});
```

models

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const songSchema = new Schema({
  song: { // name of song
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  singer: { // names of singer
    type: [String]
    // type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    // ref: "Singer"
  },
  featureSinger: {
    type: [String]
    // type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    // ref: "Singer"
  },
  releaseDate: { // date of the song released
    type: Date
  },
  mp3File: { // audio file
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: "/public/mp3"
  },
  coverImage: { // image file
    type: String,
    required: true,
    ref: "/public/cover"
  }
});

const Song = mongoose.model("Song", songSchema);

module.exports = Song;
```

routes

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const multer = require("multer");
let Song = require("../models/song.models");

// mp3 file
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./public/mp3/");
  },
  fileName: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, new Date().toISOString() + file.originalname);
    // doesnt format as its originalname
  }
});
const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "audio/mpeg") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("You can only upload mp3 file"), false);
  }
};
const mp3 = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 10
  },
  fileFilter: fileFilter
});

// image file
const store = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, "./public/cover/");
  },
  fileName: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
    // doesnt format as its originalname
  }
});
const imageFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "jpeg/png") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(new Error("You can only upload image file"), false);
  }
};
const imageFile = multer({
  storage: store,
  fileFilter: imageFilter
});

const music = mp3.fields([{ name: "mp3File", maxCount: 1 }]);
const cover = imageFile.fields([{ name: "coverImage", maxCount: 1 }]);

router.post("/addGroupSinger", music, cover, async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);

  const data = req.body;
  const file = req.file;
  const newSong = new Song({
    song: data.song,
    singer: data.singer,
    featureSinger: data.featureSinger,
    releaseDate: Date.parse(data.releaseDate),
    mp3File: file.path,
    coverImage: file.path
  });
  try {
    let songAdded = await newSong.save();
    res.status(201).json(songAdded);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message });
    console.log(err);
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I'm expecting to save both files in one request, but I got unexpected field as a result, THANKS IN ADVANCE GUYS :D

Comment: I also tried changing imageFilter, mimetype to expect that maybe this is where my error is `if (file.mimetype === "image/png" || "image/jpg") `, but sadly it's not

Comment: Please share the full `error` message?

Comment: my error just says  `"message": "Unexpected field"` , i tried to console log it but nothing appears